# MacBook not starting / booting after change done in user permissions with sudo

Tags: macos, catalina, homebrew, permission, user-account

I'm having the problem explained in this post: [mac won't start after "sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*" command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362315/mac-wont-start-after-sudo-chown-r-whoami-brew-prefix-command).

The solution proposed is to reinstall the macOS, which I have done, but unfortunately, the Apple logo black screen is coming and nothing is happening post it.

When I try to erase the disk as explained here: https://support.apple.com/HT208496, Disk Utility displays this error:

[image]

My macOS version is Catalina.

Comment: The Apple logo is shown and then "nothing is happening", so the Mac just stays at the Apple logo?. Did you follow all steps required to reinstall the OS? Did you get through the recovery mode OK? Did you follow any all the steps from https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/mac-help/mchlp1599/10.15/mac/10.15 ?

Comment: @jaume The OP refers to that Q&A already

Comment: Tried reinstalling, Catalina got reinstalled but still system shows apple logo and is not booting post it

Comment: @jaume I even tried verbose mode for opening and it shows multiple "amfi denying core dump for pid" messages

Comment: I see your problem isn't solved yet, even after reinstalling Catalina. I'd recommend that you reinstall Catalina again, but erase your drive first to make sure permissions are correct (choose APFS as filesystem format). See https://support.apple.com/HT208496 for details on how to erase your drive, then follow the steps linked in NicApicella's comment.

Comment: @jaume I am trying to erase the disk with the explained method but it shows an error - cant unmount disk 69888. Please help!

Comment: @jaume Please check this Screenshot. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y3mR20SCP7NZ9f6vVeLSpdm-K4ALKYl0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. Note that you have to erase the disk in Recovery Mode: start your Mac and press and hold Command-R, select Disk Utility and erase the disk, then quit Disk Utility and install macOS. If that doesn't work, try Internet recovery: press and hold Option-Command-R, and proceed with Disk Utility as explained above. Could you try and report back?

Comment: Thanks @jaume I tried a different approach and it worked. I was unable to erase the disk coz it couldn't be unmounted and was also unable to unmount disk. Thus, I created a new partition from Macintosh HD and installed MacOS on the newly created partition and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you could install macOS! Any chance you would be willing to rewrite your comment into an answer? You can then mark the answer as accepted and your question will be listed as solved, which will help others with a similar problem.

Comment: If you use sudo on a Mac, you need to understand what you are doing, because if Apple wants you to be able to do something they would have put it in the GUI.  You might have to reinstall MacOS on top of your current broken installation.  Do you have Time Machine backup?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can only erase the partition if it is not the active system partition (i.e. where the MacOS booted is installed).

You must boot from the rescue partition before you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**: Unable to reboot the Mac due to issue listed above.
**Solution**: Backup and Reinstall MacOS

**Problem**: Unable to solve the problem because reinstalling MacOS doesn't happen correctly and completely
**Solution**: Erase your disk (Ensure backup before you erase the disk)

**Problem**: Need to Backup Data before erasing disk
**Solution**: https://tanishqdhangar.medium.com/reinstalling-macos-but-need-to-backup-to-google-drive-before-clearing-your-disk-824530101203

**Problem**: Unable to erase disk; Couldn't unmount disk
**Solution**: Create a new partition (not volume) and reinstall MacOS on the newly created partition. (Please do not do it if you are not sure what you are doing!!)

Disclaimer: Author does not claim the method and is not responsible for any ill happenings. Do it at your own risk. ;)

Comment: @jaume Thanks a lot for your help! Hope this answer is expressive enough for others to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot from external USB media? If so, use Disk Utility in Recovery to erase the internal volume and then reinstall a fresh copy of macOS onto that drive.